# Using scanf() on *char[]

Tags: c

I am trying to ask the user for three strings, store them into an array of strings, and then print them. The following code compiles fine, but does not print anything. I cannot find out why it is not working, any help would be much appreciated:

```
char *buffer[3];
int i;
int len = sizeof(buffer)/sizeof(char*);
for (i=0; i<len; i++)
{
    printf("Enter word: ");
    scanf("%s", buffer[i]);
    printf("%s", (const char*)buffer[i]); 
}
```

What further confuses me is that I stripped off one "tier" of pointers and it works fine (i.e. remove a * from buffer: char buffer[3], scanf("%s", buffer), printf("%s", (const char*)buffer)). So as long as I am adding a "tier" evenly across the board I figured that would keep things groovy but fails. Is it something to do with initialization of buffer? Many thanks

Comment: Your `buffer` pointers don't point to anything.

Comment: It doesn't work, it might just look that way. You have to allocate space for the word you intend to read. And preferrably tell scanf how much space there is. In C++, it is much better to use a `std::string` and `cin >> word`, which handles the storage automatically.

Comment: You don't allocate memory for your `char*` pointers.

Comment: A note of caution: Using the `sizeof(array) / sizeof(array[0])` trick only works as long as you have the proper array. If the array has decayed to a pointer (like when passing the array to a function accepting a pointer argument) then the trick will not work anymore.

Comment: And also, the C-style cast `(const char*)` tells the compiler "Just shut up and do it, I know what I'm doing!". Not good, if that is not all true.

Comment: By the way, why have you tagged the question C++? There's no C++ code in the question? And if you used C++ you would (or should) have used `std::string` and `std::cin` and wouldn't have to worry about unallocated pointers.

Comment: Sorry about the C++ tag that was an oversight. Thanks for the quick comments. Just a few clarifications: (1) for allocating memory to the char* pointers do is malloc() the function I am looking for? (2) casting (const char*) is the only work-around I have found, what is the proper way? I know of useful functions in C++ to do this, but I haven't found a good way in C. Thanks a million!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A string in C is *an array of characters*. A pointer is *not* an array of characters.

Buffer is an array of 3 pointers. You haven't allocated memory to hold the strings anywhere. And the pointers aren't initialized, so they point at garbage locations.

You have to make the pointers point at allocated memory, or alternatively declare an array of arrays (2D array), such as for example `char buffer [3][50]`, where 3 is the number of strings and 50 is the maximum string length, including null termination.

http://c-faq.com/aryptr/index.html

Answer (score 0):

In your code `buffer` has a maximum size of 3 characters, not three strings. You are also doing a lot of things that are unnecessary, like calculating the loop length from the buffer size, casting the would-be buffer strings to `const char *`, and printing the strings right after getting them.

This code is better...

```
#include <stdio.h>

int
main (void)
{
    int i;
    int len = 3;
    const char buffer[len][100];

    // Get the strings
    for (i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        printf("Enter word: ");
        scanf("%s", buffer[i]);
    }

    // Print the strings
    for (i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        printf("%s\n", buffer[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Better to limit width of scan to not overflow buffer as with `scanf("%99s", buffer[i])`

Comment: @chux Yes, though to assume any size is already flawed logic. It would be better to use the `%m` or `%a` format specifiers, or create a `char *` within the first loop for each `scanf` to store the result in, then calculate the size from that to set the size of `buffer[i]` accordingly.